# Unable to unmarshal yaml files with indents or empty values with gopkg.in/yaml.v2

Tags: go, yaml

I have the following YML file called `test.yml`

```
user_name:Agent1
org_info:
  first:hello
  second:world
```

I tried to unmarshal `test.yml` with the following golang code

```
package main

import (
  "log"
  "io/ioutil"
  "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

func main() {

  content, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("./test.yml")
  var t interface{}
  yaml.Unmarshal(content, &t)
  log.Println(t)
}
```

But the `log.Println(t)` gives `nil`.  I reduced the `test.yml` file to this:

```
user_name:Agent1
org_info:
```

But the `log.Println(t)` still gives `nil`.

How do I use golang to unmarshal a yaml file that has an unpredictable schema with fields that have no values or fields that lead to nested and indented sub fields?

Or is there another golang yaml parser I should be using?

Comment: NEVER skip the errors! Check the error return by `yaml.Unmarshal()`

Comment: Also, your yml example is invalid!

Comment: Thank you!  I see the problem was that a space is mandatory after the colon for the fields `user_name`, `first` and `second`.  Problem has been resolved.

Comment: Good, I added an answer for future reference!

Comment: That looks much more like a incorrect [YAML](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) file than a  [YML](https://fdik.org/yml/) file. The [recommended extension for YAML files](https://yaml.org/faq.html) has been `.yaml` at least since Sep 2006.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`yaml.Unmarshal()` returns an error:

> yaml: line 2: mapping values are not allowed in this context

**Never** skip error checks:

```golang
var t interface{}
err = yaml.Unmarshal(content, &t)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Adding the missing spaces *after* the colon should, make them into YAML value indicators:

```
user_name: Agent1
org_info:
  first: hello
  second: world
```